# Failing to solve a simple ODE with Octave

Tags: function, octave, ode

I am new to Octave, so I am trying to make some simple examples work before moving onto more complex projects.

I am trying to resolve the ODE `dy/dx = a*x+b`, but without success. Here is the code:

```matlab
%Funzione retta y = a*x + b. Ingressi: vettore valori t; coefficienti a,b
clear all;
%Inizializza argomenti
b = 1;
a = 1;
x = ones(1,20);
function y = retta(a, x, b) %Definisce funzione
y = ones(1,20);
y = a .* x .+ b;
endfunction
%Calcola retta
x = [-10:10];
a = 2;
b = 2;
r = retta(a, x, b)
c = b;
p1 = (a/2)*x.^2+b.*x+c  %Sol. analitica di dy/dx = retta %
plot(x, r, x, p1);
% Risolve eq. differenziale dy/dx = retta %
y0 = b; x0 = 0;
p2 = lsode(@retta, y0, x)
```

And the output is:

```matlab
retta3code
r =

 -18  -16  -14  -12  -10   -8   -6   -4   -2    0    2    4    6    8   10 12   14   16   18   20   22

p1 =

Columns 1 through 18:

82    65    50    37    26    17    10     5     2     1     2     5    10    17    26    37    50    65

Columns 19 through 21:

82   101   122

error: 'b' undefined near line 9 column 16
error: called from:
error:   retta at line 9, column 4
error: lsode: evaluation of user-supplied function failed
error: lsode: inconsistent sizes for state and derivative vectors
error:   /home/fabio/octave_file/retta3code.m at line 21, column 4
```

So, the function `retta` works properly the first time, but it fails when used in `lsode`.
Why does that happen? What needs to be changed to make the code work?

Comment: From the manual for lsode: "The first argument, FCN, is a string, inline, or function handle that names the function f to call to compute the vector of right hand sides for the set of equations.  The function must have the form `XDOT = f (X, T)` in which XDOT and X are vectors and T is a scalar." Is this true for your "retta" function?

Comment: In my case, it should rather be ydot = f(y,  x,  a, b).  I have to test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somehow you still miss some important parts of the story. To solve an ODE `y'=f(y,x)` you need to define a function

```
function ydot = f(y,x)
```

where `ydot` has the same dimensions as `y`, both have to be vectors, even f they are of dimension 1. `x` is a scalar. For some traditional reason, `lsode` (a FORTRAN code used in multiple solver packages) prefers the less used order `(y,x)`, in most text books and other solvers you find the order `(x,y)`.

Then to get solution samples `ylist` over sample points `xlist` you call

```
ylist = lsode("f", y0, xlist)
```

where `xlist(1)` is the initial time.

The internals of `f` are independent of the sample list `list` and what size it has. It is a separate issue that you can use multi-evaluation to compute the exact solution with something like

```
yexact = solexact(xlist)
```

---

To [pass parameters](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/passing-parameters-to-lsode-td1627319.html), use [anonymous functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Anonymous-Functions.html), like in

```
function ydot = f(y,x,a,b)
    ydot = [ a*x+b ]
end

a_val = ...
b_val = ...
lsode(@(y,x) f(y,x,a_val, b_val), y0, xlist)
```

Comment: I made sure the vectors are of the same length before asking the question. I am new to Octave but not that green. What happened is that 'rdot' fails to be evaluated if the parameters 'a' and 'b' are assigned a value outside of the function.

Comment: There should be no vectors in the evaluation of `rdot`. Neither in  `x`, nor in `y` or `ydot`. It is only the interface that forces you to wrap the scalars in vectors of dimension 1.

Comment: Anyway, thank you, the part about passing parameters to `lsode` is just what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

The code as modified below works, but I'd prefer to be able to define the parameters `a` and `b` out of the function and then pass them to `rdot` as arguments.

```
x = [-10,10];
a = 1;
b = 0;
c = b;
p1 = (a/2).*(x.^2)+b.*x+c  %Sol. analitica di dy/dx = retta %
function ydot = rdot(ydot, x)
a = 1;
b = 0;
ydot = ones(1,21);
ydot = a.*x .+ b;
endfunction
y0 = p1(1); x0 = 0;
p2 = lsode("rdot", y0, x, x0)'
plot(x, p1, "-k", x, p2, ".r");
```